# Problems with database setup on cookiecutter-django

Tags: python, django, postgresql, docker, cookiecutter

I'm trying to use cookiecutter-django according to the instructions on [github](https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django). First of all i created a postgres database by means of docker with:

```
docker run -p ::5432 \
--name db \
-e POSTGRESQL_DB=hartl \
-e POSTGRESQL_USER=docker \
-e POSTGRESQL_PASS=docker \
kamui/postgresql
```

and it worked fine from terminal.

After this i used the DATABASE_URL as an environment variable, according to the instructions:

```
export DATABASE_URL=postgres://docker:docker@dbserver_ip:5432/hartl
```

as my variable is postgres://docker:docker@dbserver_ip:5432/hartl.

BUT when i try:

```
python myapp/manage.py migrate
```

i'm having this error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing module dj_database_url: "No module named dj_database_url"
```

what can be wrong?

Comment: Did you install dj_database_url module?

Comment: I'm using the very same code provided by the repo. I did't any modification at all.

Comment: Interpreter is complaining that it cannot import the module, try to reinstall your dependencies. `pip install -r requirements.txt`

Comment: Thanks @yrcjaya, was a pip problem. Fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a problem with pip. After installing all dependencies, everything is working fine.